# Exclamation Mark in a Schematic

Tags: pcb, schematics

I want to do a custom PCB based on an already made one [here](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/click/4g-lte-2-click-data/4G_LTE_2_click_v100_Schematic.PDF).

There are many exclamation marks used  in the schematic. I think they mean "inverted signal (not.)" Is that true? If so, what is the best practice to implement that on a PCB? A simple transistor?

[image]

Comment: For later reference, in this case, I think the exclamation marks denote a different signals with similar functionality, so it is like denoting !RTS is input and RTS output, or so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This, typically, means the signal is active low. That is, when the signal is 0, it is asserted. This is often written as a bar over the signal name, but the schematic capture tool might not be able to render this.

A common example is a reset pin - when this is 0, the component is held in reset. You might see this on the schematic as:

- !RESET
- \$\overline{\textrm{RESET}}\$
- RESETn/nRESET
- #RESET

In the `RESETn`/`nRESET` example, the `n` signifies the active low semantic.

The driving source must have the correct semantic. If it does not, you need to invert it yourself - either a simple MOSFET/transistor or, for larger counts like this, a NOT gate (e.g. a 4049) may well be more space and BOM efficient.

Comment: However, there are some parts in the file where the signal is written without the exclamation mark, like at pins 1 and 16 of TXB0106 where it say !RI and RI respectively. is it only just to show when the pins are active?

Comment: Sometimes also shows as `/RESET` or `\RESET`, and there are probably quite a few other conventions.

Comment: It is often denoted with a hash too: `#RESET`, which I find really quite ugly.

Comment: @MohamedAbduljawad "However, there are some parts..." I cannot explain the choices that the designer made with this schematic.  Only that I do not agree with the resulting style.  IMO, this print is not a good example of a readable style that conveys concise information to the reader.  Do not duplicate.

Comment: Be sure you understand the signal flow of this circuit before you assume that a signal is *being* inverted.  After a quick glance, I'm not so sure that an inversion is happening by say, U5, for example.

Comment: Strongly [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357778/electrical-engineering-needs-a-markdown-solution-for-overline)!

Comment: @MohamedAbduljawad If pin 1 say `!RI` and pin 16 say `RI` it means pin 1 is 0v when `RI` is `true` but pin 16 is VCC volts (or whatever is the signal voltage) when `RI` is `true`. It's not uncommon for a single chip to provide both the signal and the inverted signal at the same time on different pins especially when there is a use for both signals

Comment: @MohamedAbduljawad Note that on your example, !RI is in a typeface suggesting it's been placed by a CAD package, while RI is part of the graphic representing the chip footprint. If you refer to the chip datasheet, you will probably find that it is active low, and you also need to consider the behaviour of any level shifters because of the RS232 signalling conventions. In short, the whole thing is a bit of a mess and a lot depends on how well you trust that the designer has presented you with a tested circuit.

Comment: Trace the schematic and you'll see that the !TXD, !RXD are actually the same signals as TXD, RXD, except that the !signals are at 1.8 V and the others are at 3.3 / 5 V. So they're actually not inverted or active low with respect to the non-exclamation mark signals. This answer is still correct, that's what it typically means, but this particular schematic is notated very strangely, with the exclamation mark used to note the 1.8 V level of the signals

Answer (score 1):

It does mean that the signal is active low.

It does not mean you need to invert it.